# How to specify JAVA_OPTS for solr?

Tags: apache, tomcat, solr, java-opts

I am using on apache solr3.6 (naive user) and have data in the multicore of solr folder.

```
D:\setup\apache-solr-3.6.0\example\multicore
```

The current version of tomcat I am using has `startup.bat` in its bin folder so I specified `JAVA_OPTS` in it as below:

```
rem Get remaining unshifted command line arguments and save them in the

set CMD_LINE_ARGS=
:setArgs
if ""%1""=="""" goto doneSetArgs
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=%CMD_LINE_ARGS% %1
shift
goto setArgs
:doneSetArgs

set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dsolr.solr.home=D:\setup\apache-solr-3.6.0\example\multicore"

call "%EXECUTABLE%" start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%

:end
```

However I recently downloaded a new version of tomcat which contains no `startup.bat` in it but some .exe file (may be tomcat.exe) instead, double clicking which will start the tomcat server.

So how do I specify `JAVA_OPTS` and `-Dsolr` now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bhanu said...
Go to tomcat istallation folder, inside `Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\bin` you'll find `tomcat6w.exe` run it.  It will open tomcat configuration window [image]

Open java tab and specify the multicore path inside java options as `-Dsolr.solr.home=D:\setup\apache-solr-3.6.0\example\multicore`

Answer (score 0):

For setting up Solr Home option with Tomcat refer to [details](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat#Configuring_Solr_Home_with_JNDI).

Also, more information would be available at [SolrTomcat](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat)

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of tomcat say tomcat7, you will find **tomcat7w.exe** in **tomcat/bin**. Run it select Java tab and in Java Options pane write your path.
    It is quite easy compared to JNDI way.